# Transferring Keychain for iOS Apps to new Machine

Tags: ios, macos, keychain

I've developed a couple of apps for iOS on my mac and am switching to a newer macbook pro.  I've got one app in the App Store and a couple for internal deployments.  These apps have entries for certificates and what-not in my keychain.  I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on how to proceed.  Should I just backup my certificates and keys individually and and import them on my new machine?  Or is there a better/smarter way.

Comment: Have you tried any of the existing solutions that are demonstrated in other questions in this website and also Apple's documentations? What was the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Xcode5 it is very simple.

In Xcode Preferences select Devices. Click on the gear icon at the bottom and select "Export Accounts". Select a save file name and location, add a password (really do add a good password because this file will have your private developer key in it).

[image]

On the new Mac go to Accounts and the gear and select "Import Accounts".

There is more complete information in the Apple Documentation for [Exporting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH8-SW1) and [Importing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH9-SW1) your developer credentials.